# How to get the data from database using foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get the data from database in CodeIgniter using foreach loop with the following query but I am getting the last result only.

```
public function get_tags($limit, $start, $tag_id)
{    

    $snippetstagdata = $this->getDataOneColumn("snippets_tags","tag_id",$tag_id);

    foreach ($snippetstagdata as $getSnippet) {
        $snippet_id = $getSnippet->snippet_id;
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('snippets');
        $this->db->where("id", $snippet_id);
        //$this->db->like('snippet_tags',$query);
        $query = $this->db->get();

    }

    $result = $query->result();

    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

Whereas `getDataOneColumn` function is

```
public function getDataOneColumn($table, $col1_name, $col1_value)
{
    $this->db->where("$col1_name", $col1_value);
    $query = $this->db->get("$table");
    $result = $query->result();
    $this->db->save_queries = false;

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
foreach ($snippetstagdata as $getSnippet) {
    $snippet_id = $getSnippet->snippet_id;
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('snippets');
    $this->db->where("id", $snippet_id);
    //$this->db->like('snippet_tags',$query);
    $query = $this->db->get();

}

$result = $query->result();
```

You are looping through each item in your data and resetting `$query` each time but then only using `$query` once when you are out of the loop.

You need to move this line:

```
$result = $query->result();
```

inside the loop to get the correct output.

EDIT:

As pointed out, this isn't 100% either. $result should be an array and inside the loop the query should be pushed into the array like this:

```
$result[] = $query->result();
```

Then the final array ($result) can be looped through on its own.

Comment: `$result` variable is still getting overwritten inside the loop. It should be made an array and use `$result[]` to put the query results in the array

Comment: Correct, I was going to add more about storing the variable but I didn't, got lazy :( I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0):

Like @steve said you are replacing $query->result() each time you run the loop. so first you need to create an associative array to handle this. So your code should be:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($snippetstagdata as $getSnippet) {
    $snippet_id = $getSnippet->snippet_id;
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('snippets');
    $this->db->where("id", $snippet_id);
    //$this->db->like('snippet_tags',$query);
    $query = $this->db->get(); 
    $result = $query->result();
    $data[$snippet_id][] = $result;

}
```

Then you can get all the content from the $data array.
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

```
public function get_tags($limit, $start, $tag_id) {

        $snippetstagdata = $this->getDataOneColumn("snippets_tags", "tag_id", $tag_id);

        $review = [];
        foreach ($snippetstagdata as $getSnippet) {
            $snippet_id = $getSnippet->snippet_id;
            $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('snippets');
            $this->db->where("id", $snippet_id);
            //$this->db->like('snippet_tags',$query);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result[] = $query->result();
        }       
        $this->db->save_queries = false;
        return $result;
    }
```